# Find free time intervals

Tags: php

There is an array with free time intervals and some additional information:

```
[2018-01-10] => Array
    (
        [11:00-12:00] => Array
            (
                [direction] => 'Test1'
                [color] => 'danger'
                [group] => 'group 1'
            )

        [18:00-19:00] => Array
            (
                [direction] => 'Test2'
                [color] => 'danger'
                [group] => 'group 2'
            )

        [19:00-21:30] => Array
            (
                [direction] => 'Test2'
                [color] => 'danger'
                [group] => 'group 1'
            )

    )
```

I try to get a new array with free time intervals and with not free time intervals too:

```
[2018-01-10] => Array
    (
        [00:00-11:00] => Array
            (
                [direction] => null
                [color] => 'success'
                [group] => null
            )

        [11:00-12:00] => Array
            (
                [direction] => 'Test1'
                [color] => 'danger'
                [group] => 'group 1'
            )

        [12:00-18:00] => Array
            (
                [direction] => null
                [color] => 'success'
                [group] => null
            )

        [18:00-19:00] => Array
            (
                [direction] => 'Test2'
                [color] => 'danger'
                [group] => 'group 2'
            )

        [19:00-21:30] => Array
            (
                [direction] => 'Test2'
                [color] => 'danger'
                [group] => 'group 1'
            )

        [21:30-23:59] => Array
            (
                [direction] => null
                [color] => 'success'
                [group] => null
            )
    )
```

If there are no busy time, answer is `[00:00-23:59]`

How can I do it? Any variants? Should I sort through the array, subtract, use many conditions? Or what?

```
$start_time=strtotime('00:00');
$end_time=strtotime('23:59');
    foreach ($occupancy as $date => $data) {
        foreach ($data as  $time => $value) {
            $current_interval=explode('-', $time);
            $current_start=strtotime($current_interval[0]);
            $current_end=strtotime($current_interval[1]);

            //???
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each key in the array (the date) you get an array with several keys, in the form [11:00-12:00].

So what you do is pass that array to a function that builds the "free time array":

```
function fillTimes(array $times) {
    ksort($times);
    $expect= '00:00';
    $filled= [ ];
    $empty = [
        'direction' => null,
        'color'     => 'success',
        'group'     => null
    ];
    foreach ($times as $hhmm => $info) {
        list ($start, $stop) = explode('-', $hhmm);
        if ($start !== $expect) {
             // We were expecting say 00:00 but we found 02:00
             $free = "{$expect}-{$start}";
             $filled[$free] = $empty;
        }
        $filled[$hhmm] = $info;
        // Next period begins where the last stops - to 12:00, from 12:00
        // If it was from 12:00, but to 11:59, this would be a bit harder
        $expect = $stop;
    }
    if ($expect !== '23:59') {
        $filled["{$expect}-23:59"] = $empty;
    }
    return $filled;
}
```

Note that the above code expects all hours, *except the last*, to end on the hour - so 11:00-12:00, not 11:00-11:59. If you want to use this second form you need a more careful parsing of hours and minutes.

Comment: something wrong... look, plese - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ab6dc33eb7e9eab1b513b49affdd073802d6d991 . I prepare json with next time intervals: 11:00-12:00, 18:00-19:00, 19:00-21:00. I expect 00:00-11.00, 11:00-12:00, 12.00-18.00, 18:00-19:00, 19:00-21:00. 21.00-23.59. Nut usually I have input intervals like 11:30-12:30

Comment: Heh. I should have tested the code I suppose :-| -- fixed.

Comment: greate solution. I was trying strtotime()... Now I understanding. Big thanks!!